# How to code in visual studio 2015 Cordova to send auto tweet?

Tags: android, cordova, twitter, visual-studio-2015

I am working on an android application which takes data(for an instance, temperature ) from nearby sensor (BLE-cc2650). Now, when the temperature hits below the threshold (lets say 20 C ) it sends me tweet automatically on my mobile (saying that room temp low). So,how do I interface the twitter part in the code? Do I need plugins? What do I have to do with my twitter account? I am coding in Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: Have you looked at the Twitter API?

Comment: No. How does it works?

Comment: Have you searched for Twitter API?

Comment: After you told I did, but I don't know how it works and how to integrate with the app. I'm naive in this area!

Comment: You can leverage the [Twitter Rest API](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public) through [Ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started) in your app.